# Ember model: one to many fixtures, server calls

Tags: model, ember.js

Looking at [the guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/) on Ember page, I can't figure out how to wire models in one to many relatinship.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});
```

**1. How to define fixtures? A or B or something else**

**A)** Comments in every Post 'object'

```
App.Post.FIXTURES = [
{
  id:1,
  title:"hello world",
  body:"hey ho",
  comments:[
   {
    text: "Very nice"
   },
   {
    text: "Very nice indeed"
   },
  ]
},
{
  id:2,
  title:"hello again",
  body:"I'm Bob",
  comments:[{
   text: "Pretty cool actually"
  }]
}
]
```

**B)** Comments separately and linked with id's to Posts

```
App.Post.FIXTURES = [
{
  id:1,
  title:"hello world",
  body:"hey ho"
},
{
  id:2,
  title:"hello again",
  body:"I'm Bob"
}
]

App.Comment.FIXTURES = [
{
  post_id:1,
  text: "Very nice"
},
{
  post_id:1,
  text: "Very nice indeed"
},
{
  post_id:2,
  text: "Pretty cool actually"
}
]
```

**2. About fetching from server**

**A)** Do I need to load Posts separately and Comments separately, or all in one call, having them structured like in the 1A case?

**B)** What if I want to lad them separately, for example waiting for user to click ok comments link, no need to download 1000's of comments for every blog post on the page unless the user requests.

Could you please provide a simple version of how each of the calls might look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.  How to define fixtures?  Something else.**

The correct form is to embed just the ids as the `comments` attribute on a `post`.

```
App.Post.FIXTURES = [
{
  id:1,
  title:"hello world",
  body:"hey ho",
  comments : [1,2]
},
{
  id:2,
  title:"hello again",
  body:"I'm Bob",
  comments : [3]
}
]

App.Comment.FIXTURES = [
{
  id : 1,
  text: "Very nice"
},
{
  id : 2,
  text: "Very nice indeed"
},
{
  id : 3,
  text: "Pretty cool actually"
}
]
```

**2. Fetching from the server**

There are a few ways to go about this.

Use "side loading".  You still provide the list of comment ids as the `comments` attribute, but you also include the list of comments in the JSON response.

```
{posts:[

    {
      id:1,
      title:"hello world",
      body:"hey ho",
      comments : [1,2]
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title:"hello again",
      body:"I'm Bob",
      comments : [3]
    }
],
comments : [
    {
      id : 1,
      text: "Very nice"
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      text: "Very nice indeed"
    },
    {
      id : 3,
      text: "Pretty cool actually"
    }
]}
```

Use `async` on your `hasMany` to allow Ember to look up the comments after the post has already been loaded.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment',{async:true})
});
```

If you have thousands of records the solutions above aren't going to be much good.  Instead of loading all of the comments at one time (either with side loading or `async`) you'll want to use pagination to load only a few comments at a time.  In that case your `PostRoute` and `PostController` might look something like this.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjetController.extend({
  needs : ['comments']
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    comments = this.store.find('comment',{post_id : model.get('id'), page : 1});
    this.controllerFor('comments').set('content',comments);
  }
});
```

Comment: Still a bit stuck at 1st problem. I created fixture that way but i don't seem to get anything in {{post.comments}}. Is this the right way to access the comments in handlebars?

Comment: In fact I'm getting this error in HB when doing {{each comment in post.coments}}:   
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 218:
...- /.modal -->    
--------------------^
Expecting 'OPEN_ENDBLOCK', got 'EOF'

Comment: It needs to be `{{#each comment in post.comments}}`

Comment: Yep, it looks like you left out the `#` in your `each`.  With the fixtures you'll also want to make sure that you have the `async` property set on your `hasMany`.

Comment: It was async:true that fixed it, I actually had a correct syntax for {{#each}}. Are there any good examples on the web of how to do this, including the server loading? I find all of the stuff on Ember sire very trivial not real life scenarios.

Comment: how do you load the second page?